# Make a tuple of three integers in Scala

Tags: scala, tuples

I have a problem where I need to make a tuplet of three elements. Let's suppose that I have a list, and I managed to write tuplet of two elements:

```
val list = (1 to 10).toList

val map1 = list.foldLeft(Map.empty[Int,String])( (map, value) => map + (value -> value.toString) )

Map(5 -> 5, 10 -> 10, 1 -> 1, 6 -> 6, 9 -> 9, 2 -> 2, 7 -> 7, 3 -> 3, 8 -> 8, 4 -> 4)
```

I want to make a tuplet of three elements. How can I do that?

I tried this code:

```
val map1 = list.foldLeft(Map.empty[Int,String])( (map, value, s) => map + (value -> value.toString -> value.toString) )

Map(5 -> 5 -> 5, 10 -> 10-> 10, 1 -> 1-> 1, 6 -> 6-> 6, 9 -> 9-> 9, 2 -> 2-> 2, 7 -> 7-> 7, 3 -> 3-> 3, 8 -> 8-> 8, 4 -> 4-> 4)
```

Comment: A map is a mapping from arbitrary keys to values, so you could make one going from a tuple of integers `(x, y)` to an integer `z`. Exactly what problem are you trying to solve? We need more context.

Comment: When you say "tuplet" do you mean "tuple"?  The first example you show is a `Map`, not a list of tuple-2's.  It isn't clear what you hope to achieve with the second example.

Comment: Yes ! I mean a tuple. eg (1,2,3). I am still exploring Scala, excuse my typos.

Comment: A `Map` maps keys to values. You can see it as a collection that contains 2-tuples (each tuple contains a key and a value). A `Map` cannot hold tuples with an arbitrary number of elements, such as 3-tuples. As Nikita says, that simply wouldn't make sense - that's not what a `Map` is.

Comment: OK ! So it's similar to HashTable where we need only two elements. So, How can I get as a results a list of tuple-3's ?

Answer (score 4):

`->` is just a sugar notation for a pair (a tuple of two items). The universal notation for tuples of any arity is a comma-delimited list in braces. E.g. `(1,2,3)` is a tuple of three integers, while as in your example the expression `1 -> 2 -> 3` would desugar to `((1,2),3)`, which is a tuple of a tuple of two ints and an int.

What you're trying to achieve with your code simply doesn't make any sense. A `Map` can be constructed from a list of pairs, treating the first element of the tuple as a key and the second as a value. Tuples of any other arities are not supported and wouldn't make sense in that case. You can however construct collections of other types (e.g., a `List`) containing tuples of any arities.

Comment: Thanks for your clarification. Yes, I want to achieve something like (1,2,3) a tuple of three integers.

Comment: @user3001937 A `Map` is a data structure that maps keys to values. What do you mean with a `Map` that contains things like `5 -> 5 -> 5`; what would be the key and what would be the value?

Comment: I was condused ! I should know How can I get as a results a list of tuple-3's ? I

Comment: @user3001937 Pretty simple: `list.map(a => (a, a.toString, a.toString))`

Answer (score 1):

In general to convert a range into a Tuple3 you could do something like this:

```
(0 to 10) map (x=>(x,x*2,x+10))
res0: scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[(Int, Int, Int)] = Vector((0,0,10), (1,2,11), (2,4,12), (3,6,13), (4,8,14), (5,10,15), (6,12,16), (7,14,17), (8,16,18), (9,18,19), (10,20,20))
```

To join 2 Seqs as a Tuple2 you zip them:

```
 (1 to 5) zip (10 to 15)
res3: scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[(Int, Int)] = Vector((1,10), (2,11), (3,12), (4,13), (5,14))
```

scala has built in support for zipping up to arity 3:

```
((0 to 3),(4 to 6),(7 to 9)).zipped.toList
res6: List[(Int, Int, Int)] = List((0,4,7), (1,5,8), (2,6,9))
```

If you need to do something similar to higher arities there's [product-collections](https://github.com/marklister/product-collections):

```
(0 to 3) flatZip (4 to 6) flatZip (7 to 9) flatZip (10 to 12)
res7: org.catch22.collections.immutable.CollSeq4[Int,Int,Int,Int] = 
CollSeq((0,4,7,10),
        (1,5,8,11),
        (2,6,9,12))
```

And finally there's [shapeless](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless) which does lots of cool things but has a moderate learning curve.